# Why is the alert not working when there is no email address entered?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to make an alert say "Please enter your email address." when no email address is entered in this form. Why isn't the alert showing up when you do not enter an email address with this code?

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     <!--
     function checkform ()
     {  if (input.email.value == "") {
         alert( "Please enter your email address." );
         input.email.focus();
         return false ;
       }
       return true ;
     }
  </script>
  <form action="#" id="input" name="input" onsubmit="greeting()">
    Username: <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value=""><br>
    Password: <input name="pwd" type="password"><br>
    <input name="gender" type="radio" value="male">Male<br>
    <input name="gender" type="radio" value="female">Female<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: maybe because you're trying to call a method `greeting()` but your method is actually called `checkform`. Also you have a random `<!--` in your JS

Comment: @NickParsons - that random `<!--` was common .... *in the 90's*

Comment: @Bravo hm, wasn't aware of that haha

Comment: Try `onsubmit="return checkform()"`. I also strongly discourage the use of automatic variable usage (ie, your `input` variable referring to the `<form>`)